# Would the amount of balls in a newton's cradle make a difference if there was no friction?

Tags: gravity

If there was no friction or air resistance, would a cradle with 2 balls and 200 balls (or more) both keep moving forever?

Thank you

Comment: If the collisions are perfectly elastic and there no dissipative forces (air resistance, friction at the string supports, etc.), then the cradle would theoretically behave the same whether there are 2 or 200 balls.

Comment: @BobD Thanks for the answer. Would they go on forever?

Comment: What would stop them? The problem is there is no such thing as a perfectly elastic collision on the macroscopic scale, no such thing as the complete absence of friction, etc., In short, no such thing as a perpetual motion machine.

Comment: @BobD Just assuming there is perfect elastic collision and no friction invloved could gravity cause it to lose energy overtime and make it stop, or would they go on forever?

Comment: No.  Gravity does not "lose" energy because it is not a dissipative force. When the balls rise kinetic energy is converted to an equal amount of gravitational potential energy and when they fall gravitational potential energy is converted back to kinetic energy so that total mechanical energy (KE + PE) is conserved. It goes on that way forever, as long as there is no air resistance, friction where the string is connected, or any other dissipative forces ultimately resulting in heat.